# Closing stdin in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Let's say I wrote following function. Now the problem is that another function uses the voronoi.out file as input. What I do not know is how to close this stdin after sp.Popen has finished. When I don't do it, qvoronoi program is "hanging" till the end of my script and next function cannot read this voronoi.out file.

```
def voronoi(self):

    ''' This function calls qvoronoi program to create 
file with vertices.'''

    self.inp=open(self.out_name, 'r') #Redirect input and output for qvoronoi script
    self.out=open('voronoi.out', 'w') 

    sp.Popen(['./qvoronoi', 'p', 'FN'], stdin=self.inp, stdout=self.out) #Execute qvoronoi

    self.out.close() #Safely close output file
```

Comment: It's not clear if closing the file using `self.out.close()` works or not. If it does then what is the problem?

Comment: note: you could use `subprocess.check_call` here instead of `Popen`. `check_call` calls `.wait()` method and raises an exception if it returns a non-zero exit status (`0` status means success). [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23279859/4279)

Answer (score 3):

The primary problem is that you don't wait for the program to exit. qvoronio is still using the file when your function exits so others may be blocked. And since you don't wait, qvoronio remains in a "zombie" state when done executing, which may look like its hung. Also, you put the temporary inp/outp file handles on your self object, when really, you want to close them right away.

More zealous pythonistas like to use context managers to make sure files are closed properly, and may do something like this:

```
def voronoi(self):
    with open(self.out_name, 'r') as inp:
        with open('voronoi.out', 'w') as outp: 
            qvoronio = sp.Popen(['./qvoronoi', 'p', 'FN'], stdin=inp, stdout=oup)
    qvoronio.wait()
```

Notice that the wait is done after the context managers exit. You've closed the files in the parent after handing them to the child.

I typically do:

```
def voronoi(self):
    qvoronio = sp.Popen(['./qvoronoi', 'p', 'FN'], stdin=open(self.out_name, 'r'),
        stdout=open('voronoi.out', 'w'))
    qvoronio.wait()
```

and suffer the wrath of the purists. My way works fine for cpython, but may jam you up in other variants.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - my python 3.2 doesn't, is this in a later version? I admit I'm old-school here, the file handle has 0 references when the Popen call returns and that used to canonically mean that the object is deleted and the file is closed.

Comment: Garbage collection makes reasoning about the code very difficult. I prefer the explicit resource management. `ResourceWarning` is added in Python 3.2. I don't know when/how it is enabled for files.

Comment: This is frowned upon because the Python spec doesn't guarantee a reference counted implementation.

Comment: @Lucretiel - I think it is too bad that python accepted foreign language views of reference counting making implementation less deterministic and increasing code complexity for cases where `with` statement hierarchies aren't desirable. That local resources aren't cleaned up automatically when a scope exits I find to be poor design. So, I suffer the wrath ... although I think I am the purist!

Comment: Given the discursive fashion of @tdelaney's opinion, I've got to admit that while he has a point to make - Python had been created as a language of the general nature, and automated scope-based resource deallocation works well only for incredibly basic problems. This directed, absolutely lacking any magic pragmatism, in my opinion - is what makes Python so loved and accepted today.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to close the child process' stdin *before it starts*:

```py
from sys import stdin
import subprocess
subprocess.run(cmd, preexec_fn=stdin.close)
```

This won't *close* stdin, but it will ensure stdin is an empty file, plus it will work on Windows(R):

```
subprocess.run(cmd, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Both of these solutions lack the race condition present in other answers. Many commands check stdin at startup and alter their behavior, so to close stdin just *after* start can produce unpredictable results.